# SpringMVC - Error while sending a list of object as parameters with generic support

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, generics

I want to send a list of model data to springMVC.

**The basic idea is:**

- Create a wrapper Java POJO to contain a list of target POJO as a field.
- Then use `@ModelAttribute` to get the request parameters.

---

### A. Following code works well:

**HTML code:** *(of a single model)*

```
<tr>
    <td>id:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="sportsFieldList[0].id" name="sportsFieldList[0].id" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="sportsFieldList[0].name" name="sportsFieldList[0].name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>location:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="sportsFieldList[0].location" name="sportsFieldList[0].location" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>description:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="sportsFieldList[0].description" name="sportsFieldList[0].description" /></td>
</tr>
```

**SportsFieldListWrapper.java:**

```
import java.util.List;

import xxx.SportsField;

public class SportsFieldListWrapper {
    private List<SportsField> sportsFieldList;

    public List<SportsField> getSportsFieldList() {
        return sportsFieldList;
    }

    public void setSportsFieldList(List<SportsField> sportsFieldList) {
        this.sportsFieldList = sportsFieldList;
    }
}
```

**Controller method:**

```
public @ResponseBody Map<Object, Object> batchAdd(@ModelAttribute SportsFieldListWrapper sflWrapper) {
}
```

**SportsField.java:**

```
// Just a simple POJO
public class SportsField {
    private Long id;
    // more fields

    // getter & setter
}
```

---

### **B. When I try to make it generic, it stoped working.**

I tried to create a reusable generic version of wrapper, so that avoid creating a wrapper for each type.

**ListParamWrapper.java:**

```
import java.util.List;

public class ListParamWrapper<T> {
    private List<T> paramList;

    public List<T> getParamList() {
        return paramList;
    }

    public void setParamList(List<T> paramList) {
        this.paramList = paramList;
    }
}
```

**Controller method:**

```
public @ResponseBody Map<Object, Object> batchAdd(@ModelAttribute ListParamWrapper<SportsField> listWrapper) {
}
```

**HTML code:** *(of a single model)*

```
<tr>
    <td>id:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="paramList[0].id" name="paramList[0].id" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="paramList[0].name" name="paramList[0].name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>location:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="paramList[0].location" name="paramList[0].location" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>description:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="paramList[0].description" name="paramList[0].description" /></td>
</tr>
```

**Get error:**

> org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'paramList[0]' of bean class [com.sportslight.entity.ListParamWrap     per]: Index of out of bounds in property path 'paramList[0]'; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

I already searched on Google, when the list has size > 256, might get similar error, but this is not the case, the list size is only 2 in the testing.

---

### **Questions:**

- What caused the issue? Is it due to the generic type? Spring can't create objects properly in this case?
- How to avoid creating a wrapper class for each type?

---

Comment: Which spring version do you use?

Comment: @Ralph I am using `spring-boot 1.4.0`, which in turn uses `Spring Framework 4.3` I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that paramList is empty, even if you think its size is 2.

You don't show the code where the Wrapper is instantiated so, I can't give a hint why it is empty.